# I cannot get "orderby" to work in SPS 2010 listdata.svc REST query

Tags: rest

I can get the return list from this query, but if I add the `orderby` syntax, it just ignores it (no error, just doesn't sort the return set).

```
http://<mysite>/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Products?$filter=DeliveryFormat eq true&$orderby=Title desc
```

Comment: Is DeliveryFormat a boolean?

Comment: yes. but it doesn't matter - if i just take it back to Products and try and order, it won't work ("http:///_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Products?$orderby=Title desc").

Comment: when i look at the service $metadata this is the property i'm trying to orderby -<Property Name="Title" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" m:FC_TargetPath="SyndicationTitle" m:FC_ContentKind="text" m:FC_KeepInContent="true" />

Comment: This seems like a bug. I also tried it but orderby never works.

Comment: not a bug, see my answer...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you are reviewing the results.

If you're building the URL in the address bar of a browser, the results WILL NOT necessarily be sorted by the `orderby` parameter. That is because the "Displaying" section on the right side of the Atom feed results, *in the browser*, takes over. You can actually sort it right there on the screen by clicking the column labels under the "Sort by:" section.

However, if you submit the request via ajax or something in code and inspect the returned JSON, you will see that the results ARE sorted properly.

Results from my test, look for: `"Title":"test 1"` & `"Title":"test 2"` :

**Test 1 - asc**

LOG (url): `//_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MD_App?$select=Id,Title,ModifiedBy,Modified&$orderby=Title asc`

LOG (json): `{"d":{"results":[{"__metadata":{"uri":"http:///_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MD_App(1)","etag":"W/\"1\"","type":"Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.MD_AppItem"},"Id":1,"Title":"test 1","Modified":"2015-08-20T09:17:07.000Z","ModifiedBy":{"__deferred":{"uri":"http:///_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MD_App(1)/ModifiedBy"}}},{"__metadata":{"uri":"http:///_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MD_App(2)","etag":"W/\"1\"","type":"Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.MD_AppItem"},"Id":2,"Title":"test 2","Modified":"2015-08-20T09:17:14.000Z","ModifiedBy":{"__deferred":{"uri":"http:///_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MD_App(2)/ModifiedBy"}}}]}}`

**Test 2 - desc**

LOG (url): `//_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MD_App?$select=Id,Title,ModifiedBy,Modified&$orderby=Title desc`

LOG (json): `{"d":{"results":[{"__metadata":{"uri":"http:///_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MD_App(2)","etag":"W/\"1\"","type":"Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.MD_AppItem"},"Id":2,"Title":"test 2","Modified":"2015-08-20T09:17:14.000Z","ModifiedBy":{"__deferred":{"uri":"http:///_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MD_App(2)/ModifiedBy"}}},{"__metadata":{"uri":"http:///_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MD_App(1)","etag":"W/\"1\"","type":"Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.MD_AppItem"},"Id":1,"Title":"test 1","Modified":"2015-08-20T09:17:07.000Z","ModifiedBy":{"__deferred":{"uri":"http:///_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MD_App(1)/ModifiedBy"}}}]}}`

**Test 3**

To test in the browser, add this to the end of the URL: `&$top=1`

The following URL returns "Test 1":

`//_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MD_App?$select=Id,Title,ModifiedBy,Modified&$orderby=Title asc&$top=1`

While this one returns "Test 2":

`//_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MD_App?$select=Id,Title,ModifiedBy,Modified&$orderby=Title desc&$top=1`