# Get last created item from SharePoint List using REST

Tags: rest

I want to fetch ID and Title of last created item from SharePoint list using REST. I am using below url but it gives me wrong item, there are more than 10k items in the list.

http://servmachine.contoso.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Products?OrderBy=ID%20DSC&$top=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For applying `orderby` and `top` you need to call it like this

```
http://servmachine.contoso.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Products()?$top=1&$orderby=Id desc
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx)

Comment: Sandip might want to ordered by Created or Modified instead of ID.

Comment: Once you put parenthesis `Products()` it can be ordered by any field.

Comment: @AmalHashim I think you need `ID` instead of `Id`. @james-grizzle why would _Created_ be better than ID, wouldn't it be the same? And _Modified_ would not be the last _created_ item.

Comment: @eirikb is correct.

Comment: @AmalHashim, parenthesis are not mandatory and @eirikb it is Id and not ID. FYI, `orderby` doesn't work if `top` is not used. See here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58188/i-cannot-get-orderby-to-work-in-sps-2010-listdata-svc-rest-query

Comment: Ok @NadeemYousuf. I just did a test on SharePoint Online and there ID worked, while Id did not. Could be difference between 2010 and 2013? Beside that in my test `$orderBy` combined with `$top` also worked.

Comment: @eirikb I am on SP 2013 on premise and it is opposite here. ID doesn't work. `$orderBy` works when used with `$top`. However, if `$orderBy` is used alone it doesn't work