# Cannot orderby descending in SP2010 REST

Tags: 2010, rest, odata

Using orderby in an SP2010 Rest call (listdata.svc) doesn't seem to work. 
Irrelevant of the selected field (Id, Modified... etc), I can't sort in descending order (desc) the return using desc using an ajax call.

**Working**
`&$orderby=Id asc`

**Not Working**
`&$orderby=Id desc`

The interesting thing is it sorts perfectly when entered directly into the browser.

Comment: can you add %20 instead of the space and try again

Comment: Check this answer mate! http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58188/i-cannot-get-orderby-to-work-in-sps-2010-listdata-svc-rest-query

Comment: @dsouzajoel22 %20 gives an identical result as the space. It works for `asc` but not `desc`.